# Migration from jQuery 1.12 to jQuery 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm upgrading the jquery version of my application from jQuery 1.12 to jQuery 3.5.
I encountered some problem with `.attr()` for boolean attributes. So I'm planning to change those as,

1)

```
$(selector).attr('checked');
$(selector).attr('selected');
```

as

```
$(selector).prop('checked');
$(selector).prop('selected');
```

2)

```
$(selector).attr('checked', 'checked');
$(selector).attr('checked', true);
```

as

```
$(selector).prop('checked', true);
```

3)

```
$(selector).attr('selected', 'selected');
$(selector).attr('selected', true);
```

as

```
$(selector).prop('selected', true);
```

Will these have any changes in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Refer [link](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) for more information